# JavaFX: Capture screen focused event

Tags: event-handling, javafx-2, scene, onfocus

Is there a way to capture the event when a [stage](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html) or [screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/index.html?javafx/scene/Scene.html) gets focus? I tried to use focusedProperty but I guess that is used only when initially the stage/screen gets shown.

I am not sure if essentially I have to capture, `WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN` event. I did try the following piece of code in my application, but there is probably a mistake.

```
    stage.addEventFilter(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, new EventHandler<WindowEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent window)
        {
            System.out.println("EventFilter :: Window shown");
        }
    });

    stage.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, new EventHandler<WindowEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent window)
        {
            System.out.println("EventHandler :: Window shown");
        }
    });
```

None of the sysouts is shown when I execute the program.

Another part to the same problem is whether the event handler would get triggered if lets say I minimize and maximize the application(i.e the application again got focus) or I lock my machine and unlock it?